# Android app stops without any clue for stacktrace, where should I start to debug

Tags: android, google-maps, titanium

I have android application by titanium.

Now I tried to run this on my device Android8.0.0 / Samusung Galaxy.

When I open google map, it crushes.

However, any clue are left on stack trace.

Where should I start to debug???

```
 [INFO]  map open
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[DEBUG] InputMethodManager: HSIFW - flag : 0 Pid : 6383
[DEBUG] SensorManager: unregisterListener ::
[WARN]  TiBaseActivity: (main) [33926,48849] You cannot use a translucent status bar or navigation bar unless you set the window's 'extendSafeArea' property to true.
[DEBUG] Window: Checkpoint: postWindowCreated()
[INFO]  Map Win open
[WARN]  zygote64: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
[INFO]  DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:221
[INFO]  DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 221
[WARN]  zygote64: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
[INFO]  I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 11020000
[INFO]  I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 15090019
[DEBUG] SensorManager: registerListener :: 22, Samsung Rotation Vector, 200000, 0,
[DEBUG] D/ViewRootImpl@23d2e55[TiActivity]: setView = DecorView@2e8d06a[TiActivity] TM=true MM=false
[DEBUG] D/ViewRootImpl@588aa75[TiActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
[TRACE] InputMethodManager: Not IME target window, ignoring
[DEBUG] D/ViewRootImpl@23d2e55[TiActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
[TRACE] Surface: sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
[DEBUG] D/ViewRootImpl@23d2e55[TiActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][0,0] new=[0,0][1440,2960] result=0x7 surface={valid=true 529246314496} changed=true
[DEBUG] mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format *, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1440x2960]-format:1
[DEBUG] OpenGLRenderer: eglCreateWindowSurface = 0x7b3a53c0d0
[ERROR] TiUIMapView: (main) [480,49329] Enable ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to use userLocation
[TRACE] Surface: sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
[TRACE] Surface: sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
[DEBUG] mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format *, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1440x2589]-format:2
[DEBUG] D/ViewRootImpl@23d2e55[TiActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 2960) ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
[DEBUG] D/ViewRootImpl@23d2e55[TiActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
[TRACE] InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@5ff7940 nm : jp.myapp.whitebear ic=null
[INFO]  InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
[DEBUG] OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface = 0x7b182cd030
[DEBUG] D/ViewRootImpl@588aa75[TiActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1440,2960] new=[0,0][1440,2960] result=0x5 surface={valid=false 0} changed=true
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[DEBUG] Window: Window is closed normally.
[INFO]  zygote64: Deoptimizing void org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiUIView.release() due to JIT inline cache
[DEBUG] D/ViewRootImpl@588aa75[TiActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
[DEBUG] InputEventReceiver: channel '130f9de jp.myapp.whitebear/org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity (client)' ~ Disposing input event receiver.
[DEBUG] InputEventReceiver: channel '130f9de jp.myapp.whitebear/org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity (client)' ~NativeInputEventReceiver.
[DEBUG] ConnectivityManager: unregisterNetworkCallback; CallingUid : 10463, CallingPid : 6383
[WARN]  cr_ChildProcessConn: onServiceDisconnected (crash or killed by oom): pid=7317
[INFO]  map.js getCat : Load Success:http://arserver.yonnoinc.jp/api/getcat/kibichuo/ja
[DEBUG] HTTPClient: The persistent handle is disposed.
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[INFO]  map.js getPlaceInfo : Load Success:http://arserver.yonnoinc.jp/api/getplaceinfo/kibichuo/ja
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       4475 us, width=70, height=105
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       5538 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       3150 us, width=70, height=105
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       3439 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       3600 us, width=70, height=105
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2963 us, width=70, height=105
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2789 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2656 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2579 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2508 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2224 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2143 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       1926 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2021 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       1961 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2116 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2095 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2185 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2171 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2855 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2764 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2887 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2971 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2869 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2937 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2722 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2783 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2365 us, width=70, height=105
[WARN]  DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2392 us, width=70, height=105
[INFO]  APSAnalyticsRunnable: Analytics Started
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[INFO]  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
[INFO]  DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4
[INFO]  DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 4
[WARN]  zygote64: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2487 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2339 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       1975 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2034 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2703 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2777 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2882 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2948 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2866 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2874 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2742 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2785 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2874 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2833 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2578 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2173 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2285 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2029 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2059 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2092 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2118 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       1849 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       1827 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       1983 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2693 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2806 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2751 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2681 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2747 us, width=70, height=105
[INFO]  zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=253KB, data=165KB
[INFO]  zygote64: After code cache collection, code=236KB, data=141KB
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2613 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2637 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2615 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2697 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2699 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2681 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       3398 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       3327 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       5123 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       2973 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       4844 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       4966 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       4250 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       4159 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       4093 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       4107 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       4640 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       4309 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       4370 us, width=70, height=105
[INFO]  APSAnalyticsRunnable: Analytics service flush complete
[INFO]  APSAnalyticsRunnable: Stopping Service
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       4401 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       4465 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       4137 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       3221 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       3279 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       3543 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       4186 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       3240 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       3256 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       3182 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       3272 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       3263 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       3242 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       3292 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       3226 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       3733 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       4171 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       4203 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       4151 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       6028 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       3748 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       3979 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       4504 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       4067 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       3208 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] skia: Encode PNG Singlethread processname=jp.myapp.whitebear :       3261 us, width=70, height=105
[DEBUG] AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
[WARN]  zygote64: Thread attaching while runtime is shutting down: Binder:6383_5
[INFO]  AndroidRuntime: NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder:6383_5' failed
[INFO]  I/InputDispatcher( 5337): Delivering touch to : action: 0x0, toolType: 1
[INFO]  I/InputDispatcher( 5337): Delivering touch to : action: 0x1, toolType: 1
```

Comment: Did you enable `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission  for your app? (Because of `[ERROR] TiUIMapView: (main) [480,49329] Enable ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to use userLocation`)?

Comment: please also add the versions of the ti.map module and the titanium sdk. Another point to check would be using the normal `adb logcat` and stop it right after the crash so you won't need to parse too much output. The crash should be visible there